# Why does DTD error "White spaces are required between publicId and systemI" occur with Spring XSD

Tags: spring, xsd, dtd, spring-integration

In my application context file Eclipse shows the error:

Referenced file contains errors (http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration). applicationContext.xml     line 1  XML Problem

looking at the error detail in Eclipse I see:

```
            White spaces are required between publicId and systemId
```

According to other people with this problem it's related to the DOCTYPE which apparently must have a SYSTEM identifier.

Why in 2014 when DOCTYPE's are pretty much obsolete since we all use XSD instead of DTDs and there is no DOCTYPE in http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration (or should there be) does this error occur?

```
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
          <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
          xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
          xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
          xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
          xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration" 
          xmlns:mail="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail 
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail/spring-integration-mail-3.0.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.0.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-3.0.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move `spring-context.xsd` to its `id`:

```
<beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-3.0.xsd">
```

Comment: Thanks. Any thoughts on why we get a DTD error with an XSD ?

Comment: Because any XSD (it is XML anyway) relies on DTD, as any XML document